IRS forms for trusts
While working on another question, I came across several questions/answers mentioning IRS forms 1041, K-1, and 56.  Neither my wife, myself, nor our successor trustees are lawyers or tax professionals.  If one of us passes, and the survivor distributes some portions as intended to a subset of our heirs, does he/she have to file one of these forms or any other?  Does the successor trustee have to do so when distributing the residue and terminating the trust?
Does Oregon have any such forms?


If one of us passes, and the successor distributes some portions as intended to a subset of our heirs, does he/she have to file one of these forms or any other?

Yes, absolutely, the executor/trustee is required to file all the required forms for the estate/trust.

Does the successor trustee have to do so when distributing the residue and terminating the trust?

If there's residue then yes, they'll need to figure out what to do and report that. It will be distributed somehow to someone, eventually. It may be generating income until then. All that needs to be reported.

Does Oregon have any such forms?

Oregon has income and estate taxes and probably has similar forms to handle them, yes. See for example forms IT-1 and OR-706.

Neither my wife, myself, nor our successor trustees are lawyers or tax professionals.

Hire one.

Regarding the first comment, the forms must be filed when one trustee passes even if the trust is unchanged except for gifts given to relatives by the other trustee?

@WGroleau I don't know what the trust document says, but it may be needed in that situation

@WGroleau looking at your other question and comments - important to understand the roles: trustee, grantor, beneficiary - they are all different roles with different impact on the trust.

We are the trustees and the grantors. Our fiduciary duty is to ourselves and we have the power to change the trust documents (and therefore the beneficiaries) at any time. The questions are asked to minimize the need to make changes when anticipated events occur.

@WGroleau you should really discuss this with an estate attorney. In a trust with more than one grantor, a grantor's death may lead to very different situations depending on the specific text in the document.

This will definitely be discussed with the attorney that helped us write the trust. And with the accountant that assists with our taxes.  Until this year, I did all my own tax work and legal work, but it's now complicated enough to "out-source."  But I hoped that I could get info here that would allow us to "lighten the load" on them.
